# Haskell arrow tutorial loop/state

Tags: haskell

From this
https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Arrow_tutorial#Hangman:_Main_program

How is the IO done?. Particulary

```
main :: IO ()
main = do
    rng <- getStdGen
    interact $ unlines                      -- Concatenate lines out output
        . ("Welcome to Arrow Hangman":)     -- Prepend a greeting to the output
        . concat . map snd . takeWhile fst  -- Take the [String]s as long as the first element of the tuples is True
        . runCircuit (hangman rng)          -- Process the input lazily
        . ("":)                             -- Act as if the user pressed ENTER once at the start
        . lines                             -- Split input into lines
```

Interact appears to be (string -> string ) -> IO (). With the impression that it prints runs that function per line that it reads. What confuses me is, How is the initial line printed. Where is the state of the game stored in between?.

runCircuit was used earlier in a way in which it had all the inputs already generated. I'm confused as to how this version runs line by line, but doesn't appear to store any state?.

how can `Circuit String (Bool, [String])` be ran by `runCircuit :: Circuit a b -> [a] -> [b]` in a line-by-line fashion?. In a way that appears to remember what the previous results where?.

Comment: Your question appears to have little to do with FRP and arrows, regardless of the tutorial you took the example from. Please tag accordingly.

Comment: The state doesn't have to be explicitly stored anywhere. It works exactly like `State`, which is a function `s -> (a, s)`. `State` is significantly simpler, so undestanding it should be more accesible, but the principle is exactly the same. The page you linked gives a dead simple definition of `runCircuit` - `\cir -> snd . mapAccumL unCircuit cir`. In this definition, it is `mapAccumL` which deals with feeding each previous state to the subsequent definition. `Circuit` itself is just a representation of a stateful computation - all the magic happens inside `mapAccumL`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interact does not run the function per line. `interact` and `runCircuit` are lazy. Because you split the input in lines and concatenate the output, you'll see the progress of `runCircuit` as you provide more and more input.

The function `runCircuit` is defined as follows:

```
runCircuit :: Circuit a b -> [a] -> [b]
runCircuit _   []     = []
runCircuit cir (x:xs) =
    let (cir',x') = unCircuit cir x
    in  x' : runCircuit cir' xs
```

There you see that you produce one element in the output list for each element in the input list (each line). Which already indicates that you'll be able to process the list lazily. (For comparison: if it required the length of `xs` to produce the first output `x'`, then `runCircuit` would *not* be lazy.)

Let's put that together with the definition of `Circuit`:

```
data Circuit a b = Circuit { unCircuit :: a -> (Circuit a b, b) }
```

The way you run a circuit is that you provide a first input `x` of type `a` and obtain not only a first output `x'` of type `b`, but also a *continuation* `Circuit` (`cir'` in `runCircuit`). This continuation is a new `Circuit a b`, used by `runCircuit` in the next iteration. That is how state is kept: the new `Circuit` will be similar to the original one, but it may have been affected by previous inputs.

For example, you could define a circuit that sums Ints and produces the total sum. There is one example in that article, but to make things super-simple:

```
mySum :: Circuit Int Int
mySum = mySum' 0

mySum' :: Int -> Circuit Int Int
mySum' acc = Circuit $ \input ->
  let acc' = acc + input
  in (mySum' acc', acc')
```

In each iteration, the continuation `Circuit` returned, `mySum' acc'`, uses `acc'`, the new accumulator, which contains the sum up to that point. So this `Circuit` keeps state because it remembers or carries forward the sum of all numbers up to that point.

Back to that article, the slightly more general function:

```
accum :: acc -> (a -> acc -> (b, acc)) -> Circuit a b
accum acc f = Circuit $ \input ->
    let (output, acc') = input `f` acc
    in  (accum acc' f, output)
```

returns a *continuation* `Circuit` in the first argument of the tuple that is different from itself. It was called as `accum acc f`, but the continuation is `accum acc' f`, where `acc'` depends on the `input` and `acc`, so it retains memory in this accumulator.

Using continuations is very, very common. I think most pipe/stream-processing frameworks and many FRP implementations do this, including Yampa, Varying, Dunai and netwire.